# External vertex label placement in feynmp

Tags: feynman, feynmf, feynmp, feynmp-auto

I want to draw a simple e+e- -> 2 gamma feynman diagram using feynmp and I want the external vertex labels to be very close to the edges of the lines because I'm low on space.

I know that:

- External vertices have to be placed with `\fmfleft` and `\fmfright`
- `\fmflabel` gives no control over the placement of labels

Is there a work around to get the labels arbitrarily close to the edges of the lines?

TIA

Current status:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
 \begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}  
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
    \fmfleft{i2,i3}
       \fmflabel{$e^-$}{i2}
       \fmflabel{$e^+$}{i3}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}    
   \fmflabel{$\gamma$}{o2}
    \fmflabel{$A'$}{o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,b,c,i3}
    \fmf{photon}{b,o1}
    \fmf{photon}{c,o2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, please can you put a minimal complilable code starting from \documentclass?

Comment: I've added the preamble from LaTeXiT where I'm working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feynmf has quite a bit of control for label placement but these aren't possible with the `\fmflabel` command. `\fmflabel{LABEL}{VERTEX}` is just a shortcut for `\fmfv{label=LABEL}{VERTEX}` and the extra options are available if you use the `\fmfv` directly. Specifically the two options are `label.angle` and `label.dist`. Between the two of them you get almost complete control of the location of the label.

Using these I have pulled the labels in much closer than they are by default to get the following

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{feynmp-auto}
\begin{document}
 \begin{fmffile}{feyngraph}  
  \begin{fmfgraph*}(60,60)
    \fmfleft{i2,i3}
    \fmfv{label=$e^-$,label.dist=1}{i2}
    \fmfv{label=$e^+$,label.dist=1}{i3}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}    
    \fmfv{label=$\gamma$,label.dist=1}{o2}
    \fmfv{label=$A'$,label.dist=1}{o1}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,b,c,i3}
    \fmf{photon}{b,o1}
    \fmf{photon}{c,o2}
\end{fmfgraph*}
\end{fmffile}    
\end{document}
```

[image: Feynman Diagram]

Comment: For some reason for me, changing label.distance the figure doesn't change... I'm working in LaTeXiT but I wouldn't imagine that the interface would change the situation

Comment: Are you trying to make the distance even shorter than I have? It seems to only support integer distances, rather than decimal values. Otherwise my only idea would be are you using metapost or metafont? metafont has slightly less functionality so that may be the issue. (I am using overleaf online LaTeX editor for testing so can't try changing the setup myself I'm afraid.)

Comment: I'm using `\usepackage{feynmp-auto}` which I assume is based in metopost? I've tried both increasing and decreasing the distances (10,100,1000...) but I don't see any difference. I'll try in overleaf and report back

Comment: Just tried in overleaf and it still isn't working for me

Comment: Can you share a link to your overleaf test project and I can try to have a look?

Comment: https://www.overleaf.com/9739672279kjhnbrggrxhj

Comment: I made a mistake when copying the code for sharing. the option is label.dist not label.distance. I actually used the l.d short form when testing but tried to expand them to make it easier to understand and didn't notice it was broken.

Answer (score 2):

With apologies because this does not answer the question of how to do this with the wonderful `feynmp` TeX interface, but instead shows how to get the required output using a little basic [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html) with the `feynmp` macros loaded directly.

[image]

This is wrapped up in `luamplib` so you need to compile it with `lualatex`.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
input feynmp
beginfig(1);

    % define 6 points
    -z2 = z1 = 20 up;
    z3 = z1 + 40 dir 32;
    x5 = -x3; y5 = y3;
    z4 = z2 + 40 dir -32;
    x6 = -x4; y6 = y4;

    drawoptions(withpen pencircle scaled 3/4);
    % draw the fermions
    draw fermion z6 -- z2;
    draw fermion z2 -- z1;
    draw fermion z1 -- z5;
    % and the two photons
    draw photon z1 -- z3;
    draw photon z2 -- z4;
    drawoptions();
    
    % and now the labels
    interim labeloffset := -1;
    drawoptions(withcolor 2/3 blue);
    label.urt("$\gamma$", z3);
    label.lrt("$A'$", z4);
    label.ulft("$e^+$", z5);
    label.llft("$e^-$", z6);
    drawoptions();

endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

In plain MP with `input feynmp`, the `photon` and `fermion` macros are available as "decorations" to add to a path, as shown.

The regular `labeloffset` parameter controls the distance between the point and the centre of the text.  Here I have set it to `-1` to make it nice and close.  And added a bit of colour for emphasis.

If you like this technique, you can either compile this stand alone to make a PDF you can include as a graphic, or switch to `lualatex` for the whole document.

Beware that I do not think this approach is documented anywhere;  but if you read the source code of the `feynmp` macros it is fairly obvious how to use them.

Comment: This works really well and has solved my problem, but I would still like to know how to do it in `feynmp` because I find it much more intuitive